# Replacing line with its line number

Tags: shell, text-processing

How can I replace the whole line with no matching pattern just with the number of the line?

```
sed -i "${line}p c\ "$PWD" " file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

An awk solution:

```
awk '!/pattern/{$0=NR}; 1'  file.txt > outfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU `sed`, you can access the current line using the `=` command, allowing you to do something like

```
sed -i '/pattern/!{=;d;}' file.txt
```

(insert current line number, then delete line, if line does not match *pattern*).

Answer (score -1):

Another way, in case sed or awk is not installed:

```
i=1; while read LINE; do echo $i; ((i++)); done < file.txt > outfile.txt
```

Comment: This answer just replaces all lines by numbers and doesn't consider a match of a pattern, as described in the question.